# Clean way to populate content of element

Tags: javascript

I need to append content (HTML) to an element. This is how I am currently doing it...

```
element.innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + something[awesome] + "\">" + something[great] + "</a>";
element.innerHTML += "<br>";
```

This seems very messy. Are there any cleaner ways of doing this? Is the `createElement()` method the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: It is messy. createElement is the correct way of composing that. Paired with appendChild.

Comment: "correct" is a very strong word.  Some people prefer the speed of just setting `innerHTML` (something I haven't personally confirmed), but then again, an argument can be made for using the API the way it was designed to be used.  This question will probably generate a lot of simple opinion based answers.

Comment: I'm ideally looking for a cleaner way of doing this... I don't care about performance at the moment!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `element`, `something`, `awesome`, and `great` are already defined, I would usually do something like this:

```
// build anchor
var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
anchorElement.href = something[awesome];
anchorElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(something[great]));

// build break tag
var breakElement = document.createElement('br');

// append
element.appendChild(anchorElement);
element.appendChild(breakElement);
```

The break is probably unnecessary.  Just use CSS to make the anchor block or create the visual separation.

Here's a fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/30qvd2vm/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement, but if you want to keep it simple and close to what you have right now, just change to:

```
var s = "<a href=\"" + something[awesome] + "\">" + something[great] + "</a>";
element.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
```

To put it in words, build your string in a variable, not directly on the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: that is still very messy

Comment: @BruceBlacklaws - I didn't claim it's pristine, divine or heavenly. Just that it reduces the negative impact of mutating `innerHTML` multiple times (which is awful).